# Why does time varying magnetic field produce acceleration in a still electron?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, acceleration

[image]

This problem is from my textbook exercises. I feel no force can be exerted on an electron unless it is "moving" in a magnetic field. But my textbook's answer key says that the answer is (B).

Can someone explain what exactly causes the acceleration of a still electron ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing magnetic field create electric fields, per Maxwell's equation

$$
\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}=-\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t}
$$

So the particle doesn't experience a magnetic force, but it does experience an electric one.

EDIT: An alternative form of the above equation that you may be more comfortable with is

$$
\oint \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{\mathcal{l}}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\iint \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{s}
$$

This is usually called Faraday's Law in textbooks.

Comment: What does that triangle symbol mean ? Could you please explain in simpler terms ? I am new to this topic. $\vec{\nabla}$

Comment: The triangle symbol is shorthand. $\vec{\nabla}=(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z})$. The $\times$ is just the cross product. So the equation is saying to take the cross product of the "vector" $\vec{\nabla}$ and the vector $\vec{E}$.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)#Usage)

Comment: Also see my edit.